# Vue Apollo Composable useQuery Ignores Reactive Filter Variable Change Even Though It Triggers a Refetch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vuejs3, apollo-client

I am using Vue Apollo Composable with **useQuery** to perform a GraphQL query. My pagination works as expected; however, I am facing an issue with my **filters.verified** variable. Although I see the variable toggling in the client-side (I'm logging it), the network request still shows the initial value as **true**.

Problem:

When I click on the "RPRs" button, a fetch should be triggered with **filters.verified = false**. Even though I am printing the value in the console prior to the API response and it shows **false**, the network tab still shows **true** as the value.

Relevant code:

```js
// reactive state to control pagination
const state = reactive({
  pagination: {
    limit: 50,
    skip: 0
  }
});

// reactie state to control filters.verfied value: Boolean
const filters = reactive({
  verified: true
});

const { result, error, loading } = useQuery(
  gql`
    query GetMatches($pagination: PaginationInput, $filters: matchFilterInput) {
      // ...mi consulthere
    }
  `,
     {
       pagination: state.pagination,
        filters: {
          verified: {
            condition: 'EQUAL',
            value: filters.verified
          }
        }
      },
  {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
  }
);


// prev and next page - pagination logic
const prevPage = () => {
  if (state.pagination.skip > 0) {
    state.pagination.skip -= 50;
  }
};

const nextPage = () => {
  // ... (logging and pagination logic)
};

// filter buttons logic
const handleRPR = (event?: MouseEvent) => {
  if (filters.verified === false) filters.verified = true;
  // ... (other logic)
};

const handleRPRs = (event?: MouseEvent) => {
  if (filters.verified === true) filters.verified = false;
  // ... (other logic)
};

// ... (Vue watches)
```

What I've Tried:

I've used the following code to manually refetch when I click the "RPRs" button:

```
const handleRPRs = (event?: MouseEvent) => {
      if (filters.verified === true) filters.verified = false
      activeButton.value = 'RPR-s'
      refetch({
        pagination: state.pagination,
        filters: { verified: { condition: 'EQUAL', value: filters.verified } }
      })
    }
```

his works fine for the first fetch but then disrupts the functioning of **prevPage** and **nextPage**. In fact, if you press **prevPage**, it will bring you back to the initial query with **verified: true**. It's as if adding a separate stack independent of the context, which individually works fine but completely loses the general structure.

Question:

As far as I understand, **useQuery** is reactive to changes in its props. That's why, if I remove the filters, **prevPage** and **nextPage** work fine. Just changing the skip value is enough to trigger a refetch. On the other hand, when I press **handleRPRs**, which changes the value of verified to **false**, an automatic refetch is executed, so the query registers an internal change. However, in the network tab, I still see:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "pagination": { "limit": 50, "skip": 0 },
    "filters": { "verified": { "condition": "EQUAL", "value": true } }
  }
}
```

Is there something specific I am overlooking? Can you see why the request is never made with **value: false**, even though I see the value changing to **false** in the console? Could it be an issue with the order of execution? Is the request made before changing the value?

I can't seem to pinpoint the error or manipulate the issue much. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it, using this implementation:

```
// Reactive state to control pagination and filters
    const variables = reactive({
      pagination: {
        limit: 50,
        skip: 0
      },
      filters: {
        verified: {
          condition: 'EQUAL',
          value: true
        }
      }
    })


  const { result, error, loading, refetch } = useQuery(
      gql`
        query GetMatches(
          $pagination: PaginationInput
          $filters: matchFilterInput
        ) {
          getMatches(pagination: $pagination, filters: $filters) {
            _id
            category
           // rest of el being queried
          }
        }
      `,
      variables,
      {
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
      }
    )
```

Now it's working as expected, if you wrap every variable in a reactive() you make sure that internal reactive props will change and in consequence useQuery will get triggered with new values.